# Automatic Tooltip on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would just like to be pointed in the right direction for the quickest way to make an automatic tool tip appear over the > arrow to notify users to continue updating their profiles. This should be on the mobile site only. Are there any libraries that would help me accomplish this?

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1YGm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// FOR ODD REASON I CAN'T FORMAT THE CODE IF I PUT IT BELOW
// Hide it by default
[role="tooltip"].tooltip {
  display: none;
}

// show it on mobile
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  [role="tooltip"].tooltip {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

- You can use [EnquireJS](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/), basically this is just a media query in JavaScript which you can use to dynamically append a tooltip you wanted `if that tooltip is created using Javascript`
- [Bootstrap Tooltip](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp) `you can anchor this tooltip to an element of your choice` or just any tooltip library you want and basically use [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to hide the tooltips presence if not mobile and show it on mobile. refer to the example above

hope that helps

Comment: It did inded help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at balloon css, it's quite versatile and it achieves everything with just css, so it's fast and small:

https://kazzkiq.github.io/balloon.css/

You can choose the position for your tooltip to appear on and the size of the box for it to be in. You can modify the colours etc so follow your own style guide.